# keep pcs resources always running on all hosts

Tags: linux, high-availability, pacemaker, corosync, active-passive

Is there a way to configure resources with pcs command, that they will keep always up on all configured nodes? I'm asking this question because I could observe following behaviour in my 2 node setup:

For example a two node setup with two resources, flotating IP address and rsyslog:

```
node1              node2
VIP                -
rsyslog(on)        rsyslog(off)
```

The rsyslog resource is only running on the active node, which is having the VIP. The passive node shuts down the process of the rsyslog resource and is waiting until the "active" one is breaking to do a fail-over. As soon this happens it will start the process of the resource on the 2nd node. 
But I want to have the process running always on both nodes at the same time, even though one is declared as passive.

For any reason my pacemaker/corosync cluster turns off the resource on node2. I want to have them turned on always on both nodes, as long there is no reason for a fail.

Answer (score 3):

I understand you wants to run the resource on both nodes and virtual IP resource on one node.

Did you tried [cloning](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/configuring_the_red_hat_high_availability_add-on_with_pacemaker/ch-advancedresource-haar) your resource?

By cloning your resource and making VIP as primitive resource, you can run your resource on all nodes and virtual IP on one node at a time.

I hope it helped.

Comment: I am glad that it helped.    If you want you could accept the answer, to appreciate.    Anyways I am glad I could help.